# Understanding the AngularJS Approach to component-based architecture

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

Recently I dived into a project using AngularJS and found myself in a world of mess. I am having a hard time trying to understand how Angular should be applied to my project.

A little background about my project, I have multiple sections that needs to be loaded at the start. Think of it as a SPA that has a tall content with multiple sections.

In these sections, I'm trying to include components/directives. They may contain parent-child components/directives or they could be siblings components/directives.

I love the concept of modularising them but I have exactly no idea how I can let them communicate with each other. For parent-child directives/components, I understand I can use includes/requires.

But if I had a sibling components, e.g. a preloader and a carousel gallery component, I can't find any way to let them talk to each other. I suspect that my understanding of the approach and the architecture is totally wrong.

Please enlighten me and finally put me in the right direction of how to tackle this situation.

Thanks guys.

Comment: In Angular you can use 
 [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) And
 [Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) 
to let the component talk to each other and share data across different component. Go through the docs and see if it makes sense in your case. Try a small piece of code for more specific help.

Comment: You are right, let me craft a piece of code to put it up here to be more specific.

Comment: Since 1.5 there are also [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) (which are reasonably configured directives under the hood).

Comment: @fracz Currently, at 1.5, I love the idea of using components but how do i expose it's function to other controllers or directives? I don't understand how I can use service to make this happen. Will I need to use events for this and if yes is this the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 1.5 there are [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). As you can read in the docs, they should have only INs (denoted by `<` binding) and OUTs (`&`).

When you want two sibling components to communicate, you have to do this by some parent component which will assign one component's OUT to another's IN. See a simple example:

```js
angular.module('gyeong', [])
  .component('myView', {
    template: '<component-a on-some-task-finish="$ctrl.resultFromA = result"></component-a>' 
            + '<component-b priceless-result="$ctrl.resultFromA"></component-b>'
  })
  .component('componentA', {
    bindings: {
      'onSomeTaskFinish': '&'
    },
    template: '<p>This is component A. I {{ $ctrl.myData ? "have finished loading" : "am currently loading" }} the data.</p>',
    controller: function($timeout) {
      var self = this;
      $timeout(function() {
        self.myData = 'This is THE result';
        self.onSomeTaskFinish({
          result: self.myData
        });
      }, 2000);
    }
  })
  .component('componentB', {
    bindings: {
      'pricelessResult': '<'
    },
    template: '<p>This is component B. I {{ !$ctrl.pricelessResult ? "am waiting for the result" : "have received the result! It is " + $ctrl.pricelessResult }}.</p>'
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="gyeong">
  <my-view></my-view>
</div>
```

Of course, there are other options (events or services as you mentioned). But this is a preferred one (IMO) as it maintains single-responsibility components and does not expose their internal implementations (you have noticed I had given different name for the same result in each "scope", havent' you?).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful to me.